# What is the use of CHECKDB command and why should we run it?

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

what is the use of check DB command and why should we run it?

The command which I have ran in MSSQL

**DBCC CHECKDB(‘DatabaseName’)**

And I got the result as

**Result**

```
DBCC results for 'testdb'.
Service Broker Msg 9675, State 1: Message Types analyzed: 14.
Service Broker Msg 9676, State 1: Service Contracts analyzed: 6.
Service Broker Msg 9667, State 1: Services analyzed: 3.
Service Broker Msg 9668, State 1: Service Queues analyzed: 3.
Service Broker Msg 9669, State 1: Conversation Endpoints analyzed: 0.
Service Broker Msg 9674, State 1: Conversation Groups analyzed: 0...
```

Comment: I have run in MSSQL, the command is 'DBCC CHECKDB(‘DatabaseName’)'

Comment: Do you think people here can give better answer than microsoft help contains? This is not undoocumented feature.

Comment: read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx):

> Checks the logical and physical integrity of all the objects in the
> specified database by performing the following operations:
>
> NOTE: DBCC
> CHECKDB is supported on databases that contain memory-optimized tables
> but validation only occurs on disk-based tables. However, as part of
> database backup and recovery, a CHECKSUM validation is done for files
> in memory-optimized filegroups.
>
> Since DBCC repair options are not
> available for memory-optimized tables, you must back up your databases
> regularly and test the backups. If data integrity issues occur in a
> memory-optimized table, you must restore from the last known good
> backup.
>
> Runs DBCC CHECKALLOC on the database.
>
> Runs DBCC CHECKTABLE on every table and view in the database.
>
> Runs DBCC CHECKCATALOG on the database.
>
> Validates the contents of every indexed view in the database.
>
> Validates link-level consistency between table metadata and
> file system directories and files when storing varbinary(max) data in
> the file system using FILESTREAM.
>
> Validates the Service Broker data in
> the database.